# How to pass variable from Code.gs to included script snippet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

So I understand that to put a variable in my HTML template I need to do

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')    
html.data = data
html = html.evaluate();
```

and then call it in the HTML with

```
<?= data ?>
```

But then if I include a script tag snippet with (in the Code.gs file)

```
function include(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
   .getContent();
}
```

and then include my script snippet in the HTML with

```
<?!= include('DataHandler') ?>
```

How do I call that `data` variable in the DataHandler script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `include` function to evaluate data:

```js
function include(filename, ...otherData) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')    
  otherData.forEach(obj => html[obj.key] = obj.value)
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

Then use `include` like:

```html
<?!= include('DataHandler', {key:data, value: [1,2,3]}) ?>
```

Comment: After trying your fix, I was wondering why my output was only the dialog saying "Html Output" but just needed to add ```return html.evaluate().getContent();``` and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use templates much but this worked for me:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="lnk"><?= data?></div>
    <script>
      var gdata=<?= data ?>
      window.onload=function(){
        google.script.run.writeData(gdata);
      }
      console.log("My Code");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function launchmydialog() {
  let ui=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
  ui.data="Hello Work";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui.evaluate(),'Title');
}

function writeData(data) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(data);
}
```